# When to write "NSString *str" or "NSString str"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, pointers

I'm learning Objective C to program on iOS.
I know it has something to do with pointers, which I fail to understand.
I don't know what's the difference of creating a string (or any `NSObject`) like this:

```
NSString place = ...;
or
NSString *place = ...;
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You need to learn about pointers. Stop what you're doing and read [this](http://boredzo.org/pointers/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSString is a class and as such instances of the class declared as `NSString *str` must always be declared as a pointer (since object instances can only be accessed via a pointer to the objects structure).  Therefore this declaration is illegal: `NSString str`

Answer (score 14):

You *never* write `NSString str`. Period. All Obj-C objects are actually C pointers.

Comment: This is correct, but there are also a lot of type names that start with "NS" that are not NSObjects. If it's listed as a typedef in the Cocoa docs, like `NSRect` or `NSUInteger`, you probably don't need to use a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is, in some sense, more like a scripting language.  Class definitions are maintained during runtime and can be modified.  There is a C interface to the class definition system in objc.h.  Even system classes can be modified, though it is not a good idea to do so.  Because of this, all Objective-C objects must be created at runtime and accessed via pointers.  To put it another way, there is no way for the compiler to know what an object should look like at compile time.  This is also why "object may not respond to selector" is a warning, not an error and has the word "may" in it.